# Saving the output of an HTML form in an js object

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-objects, form-submit

I want to save the output of this form

I can see the results in the console for a split second before it disappears. I'm trying to create something similar to `state` in react.

```js
let sbmt = document.getElementById('myForm');

sbmt.addEventListener("submit",
  function setData() {
    let nodeList = document.forms[0].elements;
    let flatNodeList = [...nodeList].map(x => x.value).filter(x => x != "Submit");
    let objData = {
      userName: flatNodeList[0],
      userGender: flatNodeList[1],
      userAge: flatNodeList[2]
    };
    console.log(objData);
    return objData;
  }
);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Form</h1>
  <form name="inputForm" id="myForm">
    <label for="iname">Name</label>
    <input class="inputs" id="iname" name="iname" type="text " placeholder="Name" value="">
    <label for="igender ">Gender</label>
    <input class="inputs" id="igender" name="igender" type="text" placeholder="Gender" value="">
    <label for="iage">Age</label>
    <input class="inputs" id="iage" name="iage" type="number" placeholder="Age" value="">
    <button class="submitbutton" id="formbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan "Missing the formal parameter".

Comment: Sorry ,missed the event: `function setData(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`